# Access is denied for Dynamics NAV add-in

Tags: c#, dll, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have developed a dll, which is being used as an add-in for Dynamics NAV. 
When I am running the add-in on our test server it's working fine - no issues, errors or whatever.

But when I'm trying to deploy the add-in to the live server, it returns an error box with the message "Access is denied"

The add-in is a dll from Visual Studio, which has a single callable method that is called from a codeunit in NAV.

I've been searching quite a bit for a potential solution, but nothing has worked yet.

Does anyone have an idea for what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

what is often happening is that the st*pid Windows is locking the DLLs for whatever reason. Go the DLL file(s) in any file manager and open the Properties.
If it's locked you'll see an Unblock button on the dialog. Click on it, Apply and OK

Comment: I tried looking in to that, but it didn't help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. I am running a self hosted server as an add-in. And the correct ports hadn't been set in command prompt.

A very specific issue.